# Postgres OHLC Query Slow

Tags: postgresql

so i was try to make a query for obtaining the ohlc data, but the query runs very slow.

my data is about 1 mio records

My data is quite simple, it record every price change that happen, it looks like

```
id | timestamp           | priceUSD | pairAddress | ....
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2021-12-30 13:48:00 | 0.003    | 0x12345
2  | 2021-12-30 ........ | 0.003    | .....
3  | 2021-12-30 ........ | 0.003    | .....
4  | 2021-12-30 ........ | 0.003    | .....
```

now my query is something like this

```
WITH filtered_data AS (
    SELECT
        timestamp,
        "PairPriceHistory"."priceUSD" as PUSD,
        TIMESTAMP 'epoch' +
            floor(EXTRACT('epoch' FROM timestamp) / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60) * interval '1 second' AS time_interval
    FROM "PairPriceHistory"
    WHERE "PairPriceHistory"."pairContractAddress" = '0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16' AND "PairPriceHistory"."timestamp" >= '2021-12-30' AND "PairPriceHistory"."timestamp" <= '2022-01-02'
)
SELECT
    time_interval,
    MIN(PUSD) AS low_price,
    MAX(PUSD) AS high_price,
    (SELECT PUSD FROM filtered_data fd2 WHERE fd2.time_interval = fd.time_interval AND fd2.timestamp = MIN(fd.timestamp) LIMIT 1) AS open_price,
    (SELECT PUSD FROM filtered_data fd3 WHERE fd3.time_interval = fd.time_interval AND fd3.timestamp = MAX(fd.timestamp) LIMIT 1) AS close_price
FROM filtered_data fd
GROUP BY time_interval
ORDER BY time_interval
```

`

with that query, i try to achieve

1. OHLC between 2 date
2. OHLC with 15m time interval
3. OHLC for pair 0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16

But the query runs quite slow, it takes 11 second just for obtaining 2 day data

Is there any optimization that i can do ? or maybe my query is wrong ?
Appreciate any helps :D
Im using postgres 13

=== UPDATE =====

Hereby the EXPLAIN ( ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS )

```
    Sort  (cost=703946.75..703947.25 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=12784.437..12784.458 rows=233 loops=1)
  Sort Key: fd.time_interval
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 43kB
  Buffers: shared hit=83740 read=100317 written=4808, temp read=485919 written=1995
  CTE filtered_data
    ->  Index Scan using timestamp_pph_idx on "PairPriceHistory"  (cost=0.43..285122.57 rows=522388 width=24) (actual time=356.299..1572.435 rows=480549 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (("timestamp" >= '2021-12-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND ("timestamp" <= '2022-01-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
          Filter: (("pairContractAddress")::text = '0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16'::text)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 3799732
          Buffers: shared hit=83740 read=100317 written=4808
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=16977.61..418816.53 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=1883.221..12783.872 rows=233 loops=1)
        Group Key: fd.time_interval
        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 77kB
        Buffers: shared hit=83740 read=100317 written=4808, temp read=485919 written=1995
        ->  CTE Scan on filtered_data fd  (cost=0.00..10447.76 rows=522388 width=24) (actual time=356.302..1776.790 rows=480549 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=83740 read=100317 written=4808, temp written=1994
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1004.59 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23.221..23.222 rows=1 loops=233)
                Buffers: temp read=241966 written=1
                ->  CTE Scan on filtered_data fd2  (cost=0.00..13059.70 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=23.220..23.220 rows=1 loops=233)
                      Filter: ((time_interval = fd.time_interval) AND ("timestamp" = min(fd."timestamp")))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 250096
                      Buffers: temp read=241966 written=1
        SubPlan 3
          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1004.59 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=23.611..23.611 rows=1 loops=233)
                Buffers: temp read=243953
                ->  CTE Scan on filtered_data fd3  (cost=0.00..13059.70 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=23.609..23.609 rows=1 loops=233)
                      Filter: ((time_interval = fd.time_interval) AND ("timestamp" = max(fd."timestamp")))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 252151
                      Buffers: temp read=243953
Settings: effective_cache_size = '4608MB', effective_io_concurrency = '200', max_parallel_workers = '4', random_page_cost = '1.1', search_path = 'public, "$user", public', work_mem = '7864kB'
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
Planning Time: 0.441 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 29
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 5.542 ms, Inlining 54.131 ms, Optimization 187.571 ms, Emission 112.228 ms, Total 359.473 ms
Execution Time: 12795.266 ms
```

And here's my DB structure & Index

Fields

[image: Fields]

Indexes

[image: indexes]

I even tried to just run a plain select call

```
SELECT timestamp,
        "PairPriceHistory"."priceUSD" as PUSD
    FROM "PairPriceHistory"
    WHERE "PairPriceHistory"."pairContractAddress" = '0x58f876857a02d6762e0101bb5c46a8c1ed44dc16' AND "PairPriceHistory"."timestamp" >= '2021-12-30' AND "PairPriceHistory"."timestamp" <= '2022-01-02'
```

, and it takes 11.235s which result 480,549 record from 10mio total row

Comment: send us the `explain analyze` results. Do you have index in one of pairContractAddress or timestamp?

Comment: Please use ‘explain (analyze,verbose, buffers, settings)’ to get all the details

Comment: Hi FrankHeikens and Yana , i just updated the post :D , many thanks

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to create an index on the combination of pairContractAddress and timestamp:

```
CREATE INDEX combo ON "PairPriceHistory"("pairContractAddress",
timestamp);
```

Maybe you want to include PairPriceHistory as well, depending on the results.

I would most likely also rewrite the two subqueries.

Comment: Hi Frank, i just add the "combo" index but still not improving the performance
then, about subqueries, what kind of subqueries i should rewrite ?

Comment: @ItsWawan What is the `explain analyze` results after you added the composite index?